# How to connect an intent in the manifest to a Inner Class?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-manifest

I try to connect a AUDIO_BECOME_NOISY to a Receiver in my Fragment:

```
public class Fragment_playMedias extends Fragment  {

    ...

    public class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ...
        }
   }
}
```

And my manifest includes:

```
    <receiver android:name=".Fragment_playMedias$MusicIntentReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

So, when I unplug my headset, I receive the following message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(848): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.blah.Fragment_playMedias$MusicIntentReceiver: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.blah.Fragment_playMedias$MusicIntentReceiver has no zero argument constructor
```

It seems particular to a inner class because if I declare MusicIntentReceiver in the exact same way in its own file, there is no problem!
 It's maybe something related [here](http://thecodersbreakfast.net/index.php?post/2011/09/26/Inner-classes-and-the-myth-of-the-default-constructor) but I don't really understand how to solve my problem!

I tried to insert an empty constructor:

```
    public MusicIntentReceiver() {

    }
```

And that way I receive:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(3047): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.cabbonline.ndguide.Fragment_plyMedias$MusicIntentReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.cabbonline.ndguide.Fragment_plyMedias$MusicIntentReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.cabbonline.ndguide-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.cabbonline.ndguide-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

How to do?

Comment: its because your inner class in not static

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
public class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
```

to:

```
public static class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
```

Otherwise, nobody other than `Fragment_playMedias` can create an instance of `MusicIntentReceiver`.

Comment: Thanks but bad news! That will cause dozens of other problems inside the class! Ok, I will try to do in a different way.